# Conditional declaration and feedback via connect in Dymola in PedanticMode

Tags: conditional-statements, declaration, modelica

I conditionally declare a component as described here: [conditional component decleration and a following if equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668468/conditional-component-decleration-and-a-following-if-equation)
In the main model I want to use variables calculated in the component. While input to the component can be done with the conditional declaration, returning values is only possible via a connect, which is removed if the component is not declared. In DYMOLA the automatic removal gives a warning, which is an error in pedantic code checking mode.
With
    Advanced.PedanticModelica:=true
How do I make the following example work?

```
model conditionalComponent
//  parameter Boolean useVar=true;
  parameter Boolean useVar=false;

  yConnector conn;
  component props(x = 5) if useVar;

  connector yConnector
    Real y;
  end yConnector;

  model component
    input Real x;
    yConnector conn;
  equation 
    conn.y = 2*x;
  end component;

  Real y;
equation 
  connect(conn,props.conn);
  if useVar then
    y=conn.y;
  else
    y=0;
  end if;
end conditionalComponent;
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it does work in Dymola even in pedantic mode. The only message that i get (not a warning) is "assuming connections to non-physical connectors impose suitable constraints". And that is because connectors that contain only potential variables and no flow are not physical connectors.